# How can I select a object (canvas) with tag using Physics.Raycast?

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript, virtual-reality

I made this C# script, becase I want select a Button of the menu(canvas) for choice the dificulty of the game, but I don't want select with mouse I just want select with Aim, and I made this script for make this happen, but don't it works. What am I doing wrong ?

**My C# Script:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AimManager : MonoBehaviour {

    float TimeInterval = 2f;
    float time = 0;
    public UI_cozinha uiCozinha;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
        {
            if(time >= TimeInterval)
            {
                if((hit.transform.tag == "ButtonE"))
                {
                    uiCozinha.setDiff(5);
                }if((hit.transform.tag == "ButtonM"))
                {
                    uiCozinha.setDiff(7);
                }
                if ((hit.transform.tag == "ButtonH"))
                {
                    uiCozinha.setDiff(10);
                }
                time = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**CardBoard View:**

[image: CardBoard View]

**Normal GameView:**

[image: Normal GameView]

> **Image of Menu(canvas):** i.stack.imgur.com/MRIbl.png

Comment: Two options: Either the raycast is going in the wrong direction because the game object its attached to is rotated and its forward is not facing the menu or you have not set the tags on your buttons. Try using `Debug.Log(hit.transform.name)` to see what your ray is hitting if its anything at all. Another problem might be that you check for the right time after shooting the ray. Try swapping the if blocks and shoot a ray when the time is right.

Comment: I checked tags and all be right.
I will try, 'Debug.Log(hit.transform.name)', thank you for your help.

Comment: I use 'Debug.Log(hit.transform.name)', and I see that my recast only give me a hit of my aim, I just put layer that ignore raycast, and result like I want. Thank you dude. @UriPopov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Finaly find my Solution.**

When I do **`Debug.Log(hit.transform.name)`**, I can see that only hit in my Aim, so **`Physics.Raycast()`** works in the wrong way, I just change my Layer Type to **Ignore Raycast**, as it is in the picture:

[image: My new LayerType]

When I changed the Layer Type, I could see that my Script was right, and works. So I can select a object tag (in my case a button[canvas]) with **`Physics.Raycast()`**.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my guess. you are using `Physics.Raycast` that works with 3d object. but I'm guessing  you have put 2DBoxColliders on your buttons. Use this instead.

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos, Vector2.up);
 if (hit.collider)
 {
  if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "someTag")
  {
    //do stuff here
  }
 }
```

Dont forget to add a Physics 2D RayCaster component to your camera.

Comment: sorry but isn't what you said, but ty dude. I find the problem, and isn't what you said. thank you for all